# Editing an item in a list<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list

How do I edit an item in the list in the code below:

```
List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();

int count = 0 , index = -1;
foreach (Class1 s in list)
{
    if (s.Number == textBox6.Text)
        index = count; // I found a match and I want to edit the item at this index
    count++;
}

list.RemoveAt(index);
list.Insert(index, new Class1(...));
```

Comment: **You should name your textboxes**.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to describe the intent of your code.

Answer (score 72):

After adding an item to a list, you can replace it by writing

```
list[someIndex] = new MyClass();
```

You can modify an existing item in the list by writing

```
list[someIndex].SomeProperty = someValue;
```

**EDIT**:  You can write

```
var index = list.FindIndex(c => c.Number == someTextBox.Text);
list[index] = new SomeClass(...);
```

Comment: list[someIndex].SomeProperty = someValue; 
is not working if T in List<T> is defined as struct.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to use linq since `List<T>` provides the methods to do this:

```
int index = lst.FindLastIndex(c => c.Number == textBox6.Text);
if(index != -1)
{
    lst[index] = new Class1() { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
public changeAttr(int id)
{
    list.Find(p => p.IdItem == id).FieldToModify = newValueForTheFIeld;
}
```

With:

- IdItem is the id of the element you want to modify
- FieldToModify is the Field of the item that you want to update.
- NewValueForTheField is exactly that, the new value.

(It works perfect for me, tested and implemented)

Comment: Yes, works fine if you want to update the public properties of an element of the list. Limitation is, you can't replace the entire object this way. For instance if list is of type **`List<String>`**, then the assignment does not work, because there aren't any properties in a String. In such a case, you'll need `list.FindIndex(lambda)` and use `list[index]=newValue` to update it. But it is a good addition to the other answers, quite handy in most cases!

Answer (score 8):

1. You can use the FindIndex() method to find the index of item.
2. Create a new list item.
3. Override indexed item with the new item.

---

```
List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();

int index = list.FindIndex(item => item.Number == textBox6.Text);

Class1 newItem = new Class1();
newItem.Prob1 = "SomeValue";

list[index] = newItem;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class1 item = lst[index];
item.foo = bar;
```